# Problem SAMD21 : ASF4 USB CDC Echo example cdcdf_acm_write() doesn't allow to send data to usb port

Tags: arduino, atmel, firmware, samd21

I'm using the USB_CDC Echo Example for Atmel start, for ATSAMD21G18A. the code example runs Ok, but when I try to modify the code in order to send data "Hello World" in the infinity while loop

the data doesn't appear

[image]

What do I have to configure in order to run the cdcdf_acm_write() function?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57846019/584518) suggests that the USB library containing `cdcdf_acm_write` is rotten and can't read straight from flash.